# Moved my ASP.NET app to a Windows 2008 server, now DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged events don't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

Existing ASP.NET 2.0 app,currently deployed on a Windows Server 2003 machine.

Testing moving it to a new WS 2008 box.  App loads fine, other behavior seems fine, but I'm not getting OnSelectedIndexChanged events from my DropDownLists.

I guess I could add command buttons and run the code in the button click event based on the Item selected in the dropdown but that seems kinda clunky.

Any thoughts?

EDIT-
The controls are stand-alone on the form.  Not part of a datagrid/gridview or any other container control.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOCA" runat="Server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOCA_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

EDIT 2 - 
This Windows 2008 server is 64 bit, whereas the other server where I do get the events is 32 bit.

EDIT 3 - 
On the WS 2008 machine, there are also several  that no longer fire (collaps/expand).  Sigh.

Comment: Can you should how you're wiring it up? Should work as is...

Comment: Still .NET 2.0, or upgraded vesion?  Also, sounds like it may be in a Grid?  Could you post code?

Comment: Both servers IIS are set at ASP.net 2.0.50727

Comment: Are you using firefox?  have you tried other browsers?  I had something similar happen, only in firefox though.

Comment: I'm hitting both servers from IE8.  I'm going to start going through the IIS 7 settings on the WS 2008 box.

Comment: Have you checked that client scripts are registered properly? i once had an issue like that. you could navigate using the command line and run "aspnet_regiis.exe -c" in the "*\Framework\v2.0.50727\" folder to register them.

Comment: Noticed one thing: My app carries a copy of ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll in it's /bin  that file is v1.0.20229.20821.

Comment: Make sure the app pool is set to allow 32-bit applications?  (default is false, IIRC)

Comment: Scartag, even though I'm listed as an Admin on that server, I get a message when I try to run aspnet_regiis.exe that I have administrative rights on the machine to run the tool.  I'll check with the tech who set up the box.

Comment: HillBilly - Yep.  I just confirmed that it is set to allow 32-bit apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an intranet app.  Added the site to the trusted sites for the Local Intranet in IE.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. Though this seems like a long shot, are you missing an [IIS header](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx) that is forcing IE8 to run in compatibility mode?
2. Have you installed ASP.NET v2.0 (I can't remember if this is pre-installed or not)? Make sure you check carefully as some of the libraries will come with ASP.NET v3.5 but I don't believe that gives you everything.
3. Does the user running the app is IIS have the necessary security rights? You might want to run aspnet_regiis with the -ga option if you aren't sure (this won't hurt anything if you run it a second time).